# Problems compiling with changes to f2py

Tags: numpy, fortran, f2py

I am trying to update my package scikits.bvp_solver (source [here](https://github.com/jsalvatier/scikits.bvp_solver/)) and I have run into some problems with f2py generated files. The files 'bvp_solverf-f2pywrappers2.f90' and 'bvp_solverfmodule.c' which were generated in 2009 allow the package to be built in place with "python setup.py build_ext --inplace" but if I delete them and try to rebuild I get the error

```
scikits/bvp_solver/lib/bvp_solverf-f2pywrappers2.f90:218.48:

                use guess_3_wrap__user__routines
                                                1
Fatal Error: Can't open module file 'guess_3_wrap__user__routines.mod' for reading at (1): No such file or directory
scikits/bvp_solver/lib/bvp_solverf-f2pywrappers2.f90:11.19:
```

The part the adds this use statement does not appear in the old version of the file. I am having difficulty figuring out how to fix this issue. Can anyone offer advice? What are the major changes to f2py in the last two years?

Comment: Does the file containing "module guess_3_wrap__user__routines" exist? If it exists, is it compiled before the failing file?

Comment: I think that file should be automatically generated by f2py, as it is one of the module names in the bvp_interface.pyf file. I do not see it in either of the files that were generated so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally fixed this problem by eliminating `guess_3_wrap__user__routines` and moving the relevant code into python.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the 'guess_3_wrap_*user*_routines.mod' file, you should recompile it before building the file that uses it. For the same problem that I had, in my command window, which is set to 'Intel Composer XE 2011 Intel(R) Visual Studio 2010' I typed 'gfortran', which is my Fortran compiler, and the Fortran file, so in your case 'use guess_3_wrap_*user*_routines.f' (or the extension is something like '.f90') and run that. That should recompile the 'use guess_3_wrap_*user*_routines.f' again to get the '.mod' file.